# Genexus - Fonts doesn't show in PDF Report (Web)

Tags: html, fonts, pdf-generation, font-size, genexus

GX Evo2 - .NET Application:

I'm trying to print a pdf report that has 6 different fonts in it and it also has HTML manipulation.

Fonts aren't showing for *some* of the variables and changes in size also don't apply.

I can't get Bahnschrift to show Condensed or SemiCondensed

I leave below the PDFReport.ini and an example of some of the variables that could be "problematic"; although it isn't happening only on &Vars with HTML in them:

1.

````
Embeed Fonts= true
RunDirection= 2
OutputFileDirectory= .
LeftMargin= 0.1
SearchNewFonts= false
BottomMargin= 0.1
LongDotDashedStyle= 6;2;1;2
DEBUG= false
Version= 1.0.0.0
Barcode128AsImage= false
DottedStyle= 1;2
SearchNewFontsOnce= true
ServerPrinting= false
AdjustToPaper= true
DashedStyle= 4;2
TopMargin= 0.8
Leading= 2
LongDashedStyle= 6;2
LineCapProjectingSquare= true
FontsLocation= C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
Fonts Location (MS)= C:\WINDOWS\Fonts

[Fonts Location (MS)]
Arial Narrow= C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\ARIALN.TTF
Tahoma= C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TAHOMA.TTF
3 of 9 Barcode= C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\3OF9.TTF
BarCode 128= C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\barcode128.TTF
Bahnschrift SemiCondensed= C:\Windows\Fonts\Bahnschrift.ttf
Bahnschrift Condensed= C:\Windows\Fonts\bahnschrift.ttf
Bahnschrift= C:\Windows\Fonts\Bahnschrift.ttf
Calibri Light= C:\Windows\Fonts\calibril.ttf
Arial Black= C:\Windows\Fonts\ariblk.ttf

[Embeed Fonts]
3 of 9 Barcode= true
BarCode 128= true```


2.

```&FormattedVar = = '<div style="font-family: "Calibri Light", Calibri;  text-align:center;" >' + &VarPart1+ '<b>' + &VarPart2+ '</b>' + &VarPart3+ '</div>'```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the folowing section to look like this:

```
[Embeed Fonts]
Arial Narrow= true
Tahoma= true
3 of 9 Barcode= true
BarCode 128= true
Bahnschrift SemiCondensed= true
Bahnschrift Condensed= true
Bahnschrift= true
Calibri Light= true
Arial Black= true
```

You could also try to use DEBUG= true and change the property Log Level to 6.ALL, then execute again and try to find any error on the client.log file , if you are using C# generator.

Some references:

- https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=16412
- https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27500,PDFReport.ini%20file%20format